# Calling ASP.NET Core WebAPI from JS embedded in a client WebAPP page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, msal.js

I have an ASP.NET Core WebAPP calling WebAPI. The WebAPP uses Azure B2C for authentication. It then obtains a token which is used for calling the WebAPI. This works great. However, there are scenarios where it would make more sense to use a JS framework (e.g. vue/axios) for building the WebAPP page content and calling the WebAPI directly, rather than through the WebAPP.

How could this be achieved? I came up with the following:

1. I could create a TokenController which would call the ITokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scope) and return the token to the caller. I could then call the TokenController from the JS, obtain the token, and call the WebAPI directly. The token would have to be obtained before every direct JS call to WebAPI. Is this a good approach?
2. Another approach would be to use the MSAL.js in the JS code but then I seem to have to reauthenticate. Can the WebAPP login be reused in MSAL.js without the need to reauthenticate? If so, how?